# Unable to deploy custom Mule Connector to Anypoint Exchange

Tags: mule, mule-sdk

I built a custom mule connector using Mule SDK and tested with Anypoint Studio. When I tried to deploy the Mulesoft Exchange using `mvn deploy` after updating the `pom.xml` file with Organization details, I'm running into the following Unauthorized error. Could someone point out what's causing this issue or a way to fix this?

Here is my POM.xml file:
[image: POM XML]

Here is the error when running `mvn deploy`:
[image: Unauthorized Mule Connector error]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is something wrong in your pom. Maven is trying to deploy to one of MuleSoft repositories, not to Exchange. Note the URL in the error doesn't match the one in the distributionManagement section.

Did you set the groupId to the org id? It doesn't look like it in the error.

Be sure to follow all the steps in the instructions: https://docs.mulesoft.com/exchange/to-publish-assets-maven#publish-an-asset-to-exchange-using-maven

Comment: you're right. Forgot to update the groupId to the organization ID, where as for the distribution Management section part was working fine. Also I had to provide server credentials to `~/.m2/settings.xml` file